# How does Laravel extract the get parameter and pass to closure

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and coming from PHP wanted to understand some of the aspects of the framework. I have never used a framework before and would like to understand some of the under the hood stuff. I saw this syntax for the route class:

```
// Second Route method – Root URL with ID will match this method
Route::get('ID/{id}',function($id){
   echo 'ID: '.$id;
});
```

From my understanding Laravel does pattern matching for the URL and extracts the value from id and assigns it to `$id` and passes it to the closure.

1. Is my above understanding correct
2. Can someone point to the part in Laravel Code where the value of id is extracted and assigned to `$id` variable
3. Why are curly braces used? It it just to make pattern matching easier?

Comment: I think, that the first opinion is correct. Laravel matchs the url and extracts the value from the id and assigns it to $id in the selected method. If it is a model then retrieves a full collection where the id is the same from the url

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you are correct
2. [Right here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCompiler.php#L32)
3. The curly brackets are to let the route parser know that this is a dynamic part that will be able to change in the url. It could have been any other way, but this is how Laravel does things.